# Strategy pattern for just one function

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

The [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is software a design pattern to select an algorithm at runtime. See this [javascript implementation](http://loredanacirstea.github.io/es6-design-patterns/#strategy) for reference.

See the linked page, how the example use different classes at runtime. But, what about if you just want to select one function? Is it worth encapsulate those functions in classes? Or just select the function to use, like in the next snipped:

```
function getRandomThing() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * thingsCount);
}

function getNextThing() {
    return currentThing++ % thingsCount;
} 

currentGetThing = getNextThing
currentGetThing()
```

Is this solution correct? It works, but `currentGetThing = getNextThing` sounds a bit C-liked for me.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the abstraction if you have a single strategy that you'll be using. Abstraction adds complexity, which is great when you need it, but just complexity for the sake of it when you don't.

Comment: It is worth encapsulating only if you think that the code you are working on will be extended/scaled in future.

Comment: Don't [gold plate it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating_(software_engineering)). If you don't need it now, you don't need it. If you want to abstract it later as it becomes more complex then abstract it later. The simple solution is always the best, [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), etc.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to know my options and keep things simple as first. This is also the case with you. You should keep it simple for now and  keep in mind how will you refactor to extend/scale your code if and when needed. You already know you can use strategy pattern. (Pondering how to extend/scale my code helped me to learn different design patterns quickly).

Comment: There's no encapsulation at all here, but Strategy pattern has encapsulation of the Strategy in a Context class. The Context is the code that uses `currentGetThing()` but doesn't need to change when you decide to add another implementation. Abstracting the strategy makes a statement about what the strategy does (it's more than just a function), and encapsulating it in Context prevents anyone from setting `currentGetThing` to *any* function. That is a C-like thing. However, you can encapsulate and abstract in Javascript without classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the function directly.

> Is it worth encapsulate those functions in classes?

No. It's hardly ever worth to encapsulate anything in a `class` when you can do without - that many other languages cannot do without and require `class`es for everything should not affect your choice in JavaScript.

Also don't forget that functions already are objects in JavaScript, they're instances of the `Function` class. If you absolutely want to define an interface for them, just go for duck-typing their [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you lack the Context, the part of your code which uses the algorithm and where you want the algorithm to be replaced with another one. Take a look at the UML class diagram of the Strategy pattern to find that the Context is a vital part of the pattern.

In statically-typed OO implementations of the pattern, the context uses the abstraction of the strategy and the abstraction is either an interface or an abstract class. However, passing just a function would of course work, too. It's more your style of the implementation rather than a requirement to implement it in any specific way.

What is missing in your snipped then is the context, what possibly raises your doubts about the C-like style. Just let the strategy function be passed to the context, just like you would pass the strategy object to a context in an OO-like language.

```js
var thingsCount  = 5;
var currentThing = 0;

function getRandomThing() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * thingsCount);
}

function getNextThing() {
    return currentThing++ % thingsCount;
} 

// strategy passed as a function
function context(strategy) {

   var result = strategy();
   console.log(result);
   
}

// call the context with different strategies
context(getNextThing);
context(getRandomThing);
```

Comment: I think the context is just for selecting the strategy. It might instantiate a concrete strategy, but it would not call the strategy itself. And in this case, the context is really just the identity function, and should be omitted for simplicity.